# What data type should the buffer be for ReadProcessMemory?

Tags: c++, winapi, buffer, virtual-address-space

In all the examples I've seen the third parameter or the `buffer` is an integer but I'm not quite sure wtf this value is supposed to represent or how it's useful in anyway so I tried a `char` array and got random garbage so I'm curious as to what this value can be used for and the best container to put it in and if the data type is dependent on the value we're inquiring about.

After looking at my code I realized I made a really stupid mistake by not initializing the process handle when declaring it. Here is my code though and now I'm getting `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`. And `dwRead` is 0. wtf

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("tasklist");

    SYSTEM_INFO SysInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&SysInfo);

    DWORD proc_Id = 0;
    cin >> proc_Id;
    HANDLE hProc = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    char value[500];
    SIZE_T dwRead;

    hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, proc_Id);
    if(hProc == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error when trying to retrieve process handle" << endl;
    }

    void *baseAddr = (void*)hProc;

    if(VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, SysInfo.dwPageSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ) == NULL)
    {
        cout << "VirtualAllocEx error" << endl;
    }

    if(ReadProcessMemory(hProc, baseAddr, &value, sizeof(value), &dwRead) == 0)
    {
        cout << "ReadProcessMemory failed: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Value is: " << value << endl;
    cout << "Amount read successfully: " << dwRead << endl;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're depending on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11564232/886887) which, unfortunately, is complete nonsense.  Try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25355713/886887) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> BOOL WINAPI ReadProcessMemory(
>     HANDLE hProcess,
>     LPCVOID lpBaseAddress,
>     LPVOID lpBuffer,
>     SIZE_T nSize,
>     SIZE_T *lpNumberOfBytesRead
> );
> ```

The parameter is declared as `LPVOID` (a `typedef` for `void*`). Any pointer can implicitly convert to a pointer-to-void - meaning that the buffer you provide can actually be any type you like. The only restriction is that it has to be large enough to hold `nSize` bytes of data.

```
SIZE_T dwRead;
int iValue;
if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpAddress, &iValue, sizeof(iValue), &dwRead)) // read an int
{
    if (dwRead == sizeof(iValue))
    {
        // got int successfully
    }
}

char buf[256];
if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpAddress, buf, sizeof(buf), &dwRead))  // read 256 chars
{
    // got dwRead bytes successfully
}
```

If you're getting garbage in the returned buffer it's probably because the read failed, or didn't read as much data as you requested, and you didn't check the return value properly. If the function succeeds the `lpNumberOfBytesRead` parameter lets you find out how many bytes were read successfully.

If the function returns `0` it means it failed altogether - in this case, the contents of the buffer you provided are undefined and should not be used.

Comment: It's not returning zero however when I do `GetLastError` it returns 18 `ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES`. Any ideas? And thank you for the help. :)

Comment: Don't call `GetLastError()` unless the function fails. If it returns non-zero it didn't fail.

Comment: I checked `lpNumberOfBytesRead` and it was the same amount I specified in my character array `value[500]`.

Comment: In that case, what makes you think the data you got was incorrect?

Comment: It's full of random symbols like this `├ÉÉÉÉÉ■`.

Comment: @KeeganJones You didn't answer the question - what makes you think that's incorrect? What sort of data are you expecting? How do you know the address you're reading from is valid? You haven't shown any code so it's impossible to advise you any further.

Comment: @Keegan If the function return value is non zero it succeeded and the values you are looking at are correct. In other words either you are reading from the wrong address, or you are misinterpreting the data.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not entirely sure the way I got the base address is correct because it was on StackOverflow and the answer was marked as correct but somebody disagreed. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564148/how-to-get-the-starting-base-address-of-a-process-in-c

Comment: @David, Jonathan, you'll note he's casting the process handle to a pointer and using that as the address to read from, as per [this accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11564232/886887) from several years back.  Am I completely off-base here, or is that utter nonsense?

Comment: @Harry Yes, that other answer is nonsense. I'm off to vote on it. Once we vote it negative we can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the data types the function wants you to use.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx

As for the third parameter you can use a pointer to any kind of data you like as long as you adjust the fourth parameter accordingly.

e.g. passing a pointer to an int as third and `sizeof(int)` as fourth parameter might be perfectly fine.

I would recommend to initialize the data your are passing with zero (at least for debugging reasons) and check what all data returned by the function (especially the value of the variable which's pointer you passed as 5th variable.)

Which datatype really suits your use case is up to you.

In case you use a `char`-array this would be a way to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


int main()
{
    HANDLE hProcess = NULL;     //to be initialized
    LPCVOID lpBaseAddress = NULL;  //to be initialized

    char buffer[256];
    SIZE_T bufferSize = sizeof(buffer);
    SIZE_T bytesRead = 0;
    if (::ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBaseAddress, buffer, bufferSize, &bytesRead))  // read 256 chars
    {
        std::cout << "ReadProcessMemory succeeded by reading " << bytesRead << " bytes";
        //Do something with the buffer....
    }
    else
    {
        char messageBuffer[256];
        DWORD messageBufferSize = sizeof(messageBuffer);
        DWORD lastError = ::GetLastError();
        DWORD realMessageSize = ::FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
                                        NULL,
                                        lastError,
                                        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                                        messageBuffer,
                                        messageBufferSize,
                                        NULL);

        //If FormatMessageA fails it returns 0. So we make sure that the string is empty
        messageBuffer[realMessageSize] = 0;

        std::cerr << "ReadProcessMemory failed with " << lastError << ": " << messageBuffer;
    }
}
```

---

Because "David Heffernan" pointed out it is unclear what I meant with initializing the buffer with zeros I'll try to explain:

This was meant as a "hint" for debugging as I think it is easier to see what data changed in the debugger than when you have unitialized data.
**It is definitely not needed.**

Let's say your `ReadProcessMemory` call comes back successfully and you want to check the data in the buffer.
You'll need to check how many bytes were written to the buffer first and then look at the first `bytesWritten` bytes of your array.

If the data you passed as buffer wasn't initialized with `0` it may be harder to find the break between "real data" and just data that was unitialized - thus it may lead to misinterpretation. Especially for large errors.

This was only meant as some kind of tool to use during the development process to have it easier to check the data and **should be removed once everything works as expected.**

Comment: Zero initialising is pointless. Check the return value for errors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, it is. But it might still help debugging as it is more obvious which data was altered in most cases.

Comment: I don't agree. I don't know why you don't trust the function to behave as documented. Are you suggesting that it can report success when in fact it has failed? That you don't mention the function return value makes me think you don't check it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's not about trust but readability for human beings. I think it's easier to identify altered memory if it was zero initialized before. No, this isn't needed. Yes, I trust the values returned by the function. Still I think it makes debugging easier as the data doesn't contain any misleading garbage.

Comment: If you check the return value, which you must do, then you know it has been initialised. On the other hand, what if the data you are reading is zero. Your argument lacks rationality to me.

Comment: And by the way, I've not voted here yet but without any mention of error checking, which you could add with an edit, then I would be minded to.

Comment: @davidheffernan Will do later. I am currently on my phone... I will also add what I meant.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I updated my answer. I hope thinks are more clear now.